# Mass Importing of projects into TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have a mixture of about 100 VB.NET console applications and ASP.NET websites that I would like to add to a Team Foundation Server. So far, I've been adding each individually using Visual Studio 2015. Is there a way to do a "mass import" of these projects into TFS? Essentially all I need to do is add them all as new projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Source Control Explorer in VS and add as many folder/files as you like.

[image]

Comment: I can think of two downside: adding unneeded files and timeouts. I would suggest to prepare by adding .tfignore files, removing unneeded folders and use the tf command line.

Comment: That is another option.  Remember too the wizard does provide an opportunity to exclude files/folders by type or name.